# Whats the best way to sort and search for similar embeddings for facial recognition

Tags: algorithm, sorting, face-recognition, database-management, deepface

I'm planning on making a rather large database of faces/embeddings. I want to know whats the best way to sort my list of embeddings and I also want to know what's the best way to search my list for the most similar face. I'm using deepface for my facial recognition and identification.

Comment: What do you call an *embedding* ?

Comment: Best in what sense ?

Answer (score -1):

Assume `df['embeddings']` has a collection of all the embeddings you want to match against

`face_embedding` is the one you're finding the nearest match to

Define the distance function

```
def find_distance(x):
  if x is not None:
    return distance.euclidean(x.detach().numpy(), face_embedding.detach().numpy())
  else:
    return None
```

Apply the distance function to the 'embeddings' column of the dataframe

```
df['distance'] = df['embeddings'].apply(find_distance)
```

Find the index of the closest match

```
closest_index = df['distance'].idxmin()

return closest_index
```